# Streamlit AG-Grid strange behavior

Tags: python-3.x, ag-grid, streamlit

The following are part of a streamlit python code using AGGrid to extract data from a snowflake table and       allow user to edit data in the grid, but when I try to update a cell's value, always the 1st time it doesn't work then       2nd time it works then 3rd time doesn't work and 4th time works again. Everytime after I updated a cell I can see       the Running... icon on top right corner and I am pretty sure that it rerun the python script everytime, but why it          react like this? Is that any parameter setting wrong in AgGrid? I was debugging by displaying out df_from_grid           dataframe, it shows the updated cell value on 2nd, 4th, 6th times cell update only.

```
gd = GridOptionsBuilder.from_dataframe(st.session_state.df_for_grid,enableRowGroup=True, enableValue=True, enablePivot=True, use_container_width=True)
# gd.configure_side_bar()
# Frank comment - allow multiple selection
gd.configure_selection("multiple")
# Frank - comment - per page 25 rows
gd.configure_pagination(enabled=True,paginationAutoPageSize=False ,paginationPageSize=25)
# Frank - comment - columns sortable
gd.configure_default_column( groupable=True,sortable=True)
gd.configure_selection(selection_mode="multiple", use_checkbox=True)
gd.configure_column('MASTER_ORG_CODE', editable=True)
gd.configure_column('FINANCE_ORG_CODE', editable=True)
# gd.configure_auto_height(autoHeight = True)
gd.configure_column('IN_USE', editable=True,cellEditor='agSelectCellEditor', cellEditorParams={'values': flag })
gd.configure_column('ROW_ID', hide=True)
gd.configure_column('YEAR', hide=True)
# Frank - comment call OnCellValueChanged
gd.configure_grid_options(onCellValueChanged=js) 
# gd.configure_default_column(cellStyle={'color': color, 'font-size': str(fontsize)+'px' })

# Frank Comment - build the grid and store in gridoptions variable
gridoptions = gd.build()

if add_row_button:
    st.session_state.df_for_grid = add_row( st.session_state.df_for_grid)
    st.experimental_rerun()

# st.write('**:green[----------------------------------------------------------------]**')

# Frank - Comment - Start writing the main Data grid
st.subheader(" **:blue[DATA]**")
# st.write('**:green[----------------------------------------------------------------]**')

# Frank comment - consider change to GridUpdateMode.MANUAL and add a commit button 
# https://streamlit-aggrid.readthedocs.io/en/docs/AgGrid.html
grid_table = AgGrid(
    st.session_state.df_for_grid,
    enable_enterprise_modules=True,
    data_return_mode=DataReturnMode.AS_INPUT,
    gridOptions=gridoptions,
    #height = '100%',
    # width = '200%',
    # Frank comment - prevent auto reloading data
    reload_data=False, 
    # id = 'MASTER_ORG_CODE',
    update_mode=GridUpdateMode.MODEL_CHANGED | GridUpdateMode.VALUE_CHANGED,
    # update_mode=GridUpdateMode.GRID_CHANGED,
    theme='balham',
    # theme = 'light',
    allow_unsafe_jscode=True,
)

df_from_grid =  grid_table["data"]

# Frank comment - data cleaning and transformation
df_from_grid['MODIFIED_TIMESTAMP'] = df_from_grid['MODIFIED_TIMESTAMP'].astype(str)
df_from_grid.loc[df_from_grid['MODIFIED_TIMESTAMP']== 'None', 'MODIFIED_TIMESTAMP'] = None
df_from_grid['DEFAULT_RC'] = df_from_grid['DEFAULT_RC'].astype(str)
df_from_grid.loc[df_from_grid['DEFAULT_RC'] == 'None', 'DEFAULT_RC'] = None

# Frank comment - selected rows storing in dataframe df_sel_row
sel_row = grid_table["selected_rows"]
df_sel_row = pd.DataFrame(sel_row)

df_from_grid = pd.DataFrame(df_from_grid)
# Frank - comment debug Add a line to display the current time
current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
st.write(f"Current Time: {current_time}")

# Frank - Debugging display df_from_grid { problem is that df_from_grid didn't get the correct changes reflect in this dataframe }
st.subheader("**:blue[DF_FROM_GRID 0]** ❄️")
st.dataframe(df_from_grid)
```